# Vectorized version of the finite difference method using python

Tags: python, vectorization, difference, differential-equations

I need to implement the finite difference method in python. However, I want to do it using a vectorized version. I want to solve the equation 'dA(z,t)/dz = - alpha*A(z,t)'. Where z,t are the spatial and the temporal coordinates of the function A. Which is considered as a vector.

I have initialized A0 = a0*np.exp(-(t/t0)**2) which is a Gaussian field. I gave implemented a function that carries out the finite difference method (using the central Euler formula).

```
    A0 = a0*np.exp(-(t/t0)**2)
    def fd_1d(alpha=0.5, L, h):
        L = 5  # the length of propagation
        h = 0.5  # stepsize
        initfield = A0  # initial field
        for i,j in enumerate(np.arange(0,self.L + 0.5 , 0.5)):
                initfield[:][i+1] = initfield[:][i-1] - 2*(0.5)*(alpha)*initfield[:][i]
            return initfield
```

What I want to do, is to define the new vector (i.e. initfield[:][i+1]) as a function of the old vectors (i.e. initfield[:][i-1],initfield[:][i]). However It doesn't seem to be working, because it doesn't perform the subtraction of the whole vector field. it does the subtraction of point by point. Does anyone know how to carry out this using a vectorized version.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation to the one actually used in your code? As you know, in python it is part of the grammar. And how is `initfield` declared?

Comment: What you are trying to implement is called the central Euler method or Nystrom 2-tap method. It is weakly stable and very sensitive to the choice of approximation of the first step for `initfield[:][1]`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann , I fixed it in my code. the initfield takes the values of the A0 declared previously. In fact, the problem is to find the new field which is given as a function of the preceding field at the position [i] and [i-1]. But I can't carry out this operation because they are defined as vectors and not a one element.

Comment: This still does not make sense. Logically you should set `initfield[:][0] = A0`, and you still need to define the next element by some other method, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067889/115115 for the effects of this first step.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Thank you for your answer. In fact, the problem remains present. I understand, that you think the method is  not correctly indexed (I agree). This is not my problem. What I want to do, is to create an array and to index it (the whole array) with an index i. and carry out the procedure. However, when I create an array and I index it. The python point to the i^{th} value in the array. Thank you for you help. I can send you the code and compile it to see the problem. thanks

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Thank you for your help. I fixed the problem. It was just a matter of how I should define the array ''initfield''. Thank you again. ;)